# Replace String with Objects from Array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string, replace

Hi I'm building an iPhone app which loads a html string from a local file and edits it. This htm file contains a table that contains multiple cells. The contents of each cell is cell0, cell1, cell2, cell3, etc...

What I'm doing is replacing the contents of those cells with data from the array. I first search for the string in the htm file and replace it with a string from the array as such:

```
[modifiedHtm replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"cell0" withString:[array objectAtIndex:0] options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, modifiedHtm.length)];
[modifiedHtm replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"cell1" withString:[array objectAtIndex:1] options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, modifiedHtm.length)];
[modifiedHtm replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"cell2" withString:[array objectAtIndex:2] options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, modifiedHtm.length)];
[modifiedHtm replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"cell3" withString:[array objectAtIndex:3] options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, modifiedHtm.length)];
```

Each cell is replaced by the corresponding object from the array, i.e. cell2 is replaced by object 2 of the array.

This array is quite long and I have several of them, each with varying amounts of objects.

Is there a way to tell it to replace occurrence of string "cell(n)" with String [array objectAtIndex:(n)] where n is an integer between 0 and say 75?

Comment: Well, the `ofString` value can be a variable which you calculate with a stringWithFormat statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such a method, but you can easily do it manually by putting it into the loop, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
    NSString *cellString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%d", i];
    [modifiedHtm replaceOccurrencesOfString:cellString withString:[array objectAtIndex:i] options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, modifiedHtm.length)];
}
```

If you do it for every cell, just to display it in cell, the best solution is to put it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: method:

```
NSString *cellString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%d", indexPath.row];
        [modifiedHtm replaceOccurrencesOfString:cellString withString:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, modifiedHtm.length)];
```

Hope this help.